# How to programmatically remove Kafka consumer

Tags: spring-kafka

I already know how to add dynamically created listeners at runtime (i.e. after the spring context was loaded, when the application already runs). I also know how to stop them. But how do I completely remove them, so I can create new listeners in their stead?

My listener class (generic):

```
    public class KafkaListener<IN> implements MessageListener<String, String> { 

        private final Class<IN> inType;

        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> data) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

gets registered as a listener like this:

```
    MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> listenerEndpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<>();
    listenerEndpoint.setId(LISTENER_ID);
    listenerEndpoint.setGroupId(kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getGroupId());
    listenerEndpoint.setAutoStartup(true);
    listenerEndpoint.setTopics(topic);
    listenerEndpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory());
    
    listenerEndpoint.setBean(listener); // <-- the listener is a KafkaListener as defined above
    listenerEndpoint.setMethod(listener.getClass().getMethod("onMessage", ConsumerRecord.class));
    kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(listenerEndpoint, kafkaListenerContainerFactory, true);
```

where the `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` is autowired.

I can later stop the listener using:

```
    kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(LISTENER_ID).stop();
```

But how do I completely remove the container from the registry, so I can register a new one in its stead?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to remove a container from the registry.

However, there is no need to use the provided registry for this use case, simply use the container factory to create the container yourself and use your own registry (e.g. a simple `Map`).